# Unity - Character Motor Forward Dash issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to modify Unity's built-in character motor to allow my character to dash forward when the user presses the dash button. This dash feature is simple, I just wish to dash the character forward in the direction they are facing quickly, with a travel distance of about 3 meters. Here is the code I have so far:

Inside the update() function this function is called if the dash input key has been pressed

```
private function ApplyInputDashForce (velocity : Vector3) {

    if (!inputDash || !canControl)
        dashing.lastButtonDownTime = -100;

    if (inputJump && jumping.lastButtonDownTime < 0 && canControl)
        dashing.lastButtonDownTime = Time.time;

    if (dashing.enabled && canControl) // && (Time.time - dashing.lastButtonDownTime < 0.2) 
    {            
        dashing.dashing = true;
        dashing.lastButtonDownTime = -100;
        dashing.dashCounter ++;
        var cam : Transform = Camera.main.transform;
        dashing.dashDir = Vector3(cam.localPosition.x, 0, cam.localPosition.y); //(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));            
        velocity += dashing.dashDir * dashing.baseDistance;
        Debug.Log("We just dashed.");            
    }       

    return velocity;
}
```

I have managed to get the dash to work somewhat the only problem is that it wouldn't dash in the right direction. But dash across the X axis only. I need to be able to dash in the direction the player is facing. I have also tried this

```
dashing.dashDir = Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));            
velocity += dashing.dashDir * dashing.baseDistance;
```

Any help  as to what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your character controller is fps then don't just change the value of particular axis change the CharacterMotor.maxForwardSpeed and revert back it when button is released.

The dash will be in the direction character facing.

```
gameObject.GetComponent(CharacterMotor).maxForwardSpeed =  gameObject.GetComponent(CharacterMotor).maxForwardSpeed * (((speed)/100.0)+1);
```

pass the character motor of your TPS or FPS controller.

Comment: No see this won't work unfortunately, because I don't want my fps controller to have to be moving in order for the dash to work. I just want the ability to be stood still (if necessary) and press dash and shoot forward about 3-4 meters then loose all momentum.